# Fadeout div after executing script with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

With this function I want to submit data (res_id) to a script and fadeout the div by it's id (using variable pos), the script is executed but the div won't fade out. Why is that?

```
$('.remove_resort').click(function() {
    pos = $(this).attr("id");
    rem_res();
});

function rem_res() {
    $.get("/snowreport/request/remove.php", {
        res_id: pos
    }, function(data1) {
        pos.fadeOut("slow");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pos` contains the ID string, so you need `$("#" + pos).fadeOut("slow")`

Comment: but wait... he set pos by calling `$(this).attr("id")`. If he just set  pos to `$(this)` then he wouldn't have to recreate a new jQuery object. Also it would work with any object that doesn't have an ID. Also by passing the element to his function he'd also avoid `pos` being a globally-scoped variable.

Answer (score 0):

`pos` is outscoped. You should pass it as an argument to the function.

```
$('.remove_resort').click(function() {
    pos = $(this).attr("id");
    rem_res(pos);
});

function rem_res(pos) {
    $.get("/snowreport/request/remove.php", {
        res_id: pos
    }, function(data1) {
        pos.fadeOut("slow");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're storing `pos = $(this).attr("id")`, which is a string, not a jQuery object. What your original code is doing is trying to call "somestring".fadeOut(), which won't work. If you keep a reference to the jQuery object for the element and call fadeOut on that, it should fade out.

---

Let's rewrite this code so that it does what you're after, is a little cleaner and more obvious:

```
$('.remove_resort').click(function() {
    rem_res(this);
});

function rem_res(element) {
    var $element = $(element),
        id = element.id;

    $.get("/snowreport/request/remove.php", { res_id: id }, function(data) {
        $element.fadeOut("slow");
    });
}
```